# Pandas DataFrame.update with MultiIndex label

Tags: pandas

Given a DataFrame A with MultiIndex and a DataFrame B with one-dimensional index, how to update column values of A with new values from B where the index of B should be matched with the second index label of A.

Test data:

```
begin = [10, 10, 12, 12, 14, 14]
end = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
values_updated = [10, 20, 3, 4, 50, 60]

multiindexed = pd.DataFrame({'begin': begin,
                             'end': end,
                             'value': values})
multiindexed.set_index(['begin', 'end'], inplace=True)

singleindexed = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip([10, 11, 14, 15],
                                            [10, 20, 50, 60])),
                                   orient='index')
singleindexed.columns = ['value']
```

And the desired result should be

```
               value
begin end       
10    10       10
      11       20
12    12       3
      13       4
14    14       50
      15       60
```

Now I was thinking about a variant of

```
multiindexed.update(singleindexed)
```

I searched the docs of `DataFrame.update`, but could not find anything w.r.t. index handling.

Am I missing an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for selecting data in `multiindexed` and then set new values by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
print singleindexed.index
Int64Index([10, 11, 14, 15], dtype='int64')

print singleindexed.values
[[10]
 [20]
 [50]
 [60]]

idx = pd.IndexSlice

print multiindexed.loc[idx[:, singleindexed.index],:]
           value
start end       
10    10       1
      11       2
14    14       5
      15       6

multiindexed.loc[idx[:, singleindexed.index],:] = singleindexed.values
print multiindexed
           value
start end       
10    10      10
      11      20
12    12       3
      13       4
14    14      50
      15      60
```

[Using slicers in docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers).