# Pandas broadcast across primary label of MultiIndex

Tags: pandas

Given a DataFrame A with MultiIndex and a DataFrame B with one-dimensional index, how to update column values of A with new values from B where the index of B should be matched with the first index label of A.  The values of A should be "broadcast" across the lower-level index labels.

Test data:

```
begin = [10, 10, 12, 12, 14, 14]
end = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

mi = pd.DataFrame({'begin': begin,
                   'end': end,
                   'value': values})
mi.set_index(['begin', 'end'], inplace=True)

si = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip([10, 12],
                                     [10, 20])), orient='index')
si.columns = ['value']
```

And the desired result should be

```
            value
begin end       
10    10       10
      11       10
12    12       20
      13       20
14    14       5
      15       6
```

I was trying to come up with a solution based on [Pandas DataFrame.update with MultiIndex label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113943/pandas-dataframe-update-with-multiindex-label), but to no avail so far because of fewer values in DataFrame B (`si`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how my decision is good enough but please try it :)

```
mi.update(pd.merge(mi.reset_index(), si.reset_index(), left_on='begin', right_on='index', suffixes=('_x', '')).set_index(['begin', 'end']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcasting like this:

```
_, si_broadcast = mi.align(si.rename_axis(index="begin"))
mi_updated = mi.mask(~pd.isna(si_broadcast), si_broadcast)
```

1. rename the index in `si` to *begin* so that it matches the index level it corresponds to in `mi`
2. Use `align` for explicit broadcasting
3. Create an update that takes the value from si if it exists, else takes from `mi` using mask.